# Task bar progress

Tags: java, windows, icons, progress-bar, taskbar

I've notice that some programs when they load, the icon in the task bar shows the progress, at least for windows 7. I wonder how to use that ability.

Like show in the image below:

[image: http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/9569/loadingj.jpg]

Comment: This fonction seems to be easier to be implemented in a .net application http://weblogs.asp.net/sergeyzwezdin/archive/2009/04/30/windows-7-programming-taskbar-part-1-progress-bar.aspx

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167037/windows-7-taskbar-progress-bar-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You need SetProgressState and SetProgressValue from the [ITaskbarList3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391692%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface.

From Java you could try [BridJ](http://nativelibs4java.sourceforge.net/bridj/api/stable/org/bridj/cpp/com/shell/ITaskbarList3.html).

Comment: Yes, you can have a look at this example program that makes full use of BridJ's ITaskbarList3 binding : https://github.com/ochafik/nativelibs4java/blob/master/libraries/Runtime/BridJ/src/main/demos/TaskbarListDemo.java