# JFrame icon change on progress

Tags: java, jframe, java-7, progress, imageicon

I have a simple java application that handles long lasting tasks. I want to show the progress in the windows task bar with a corresponding icon.

The software will run on Windows 7, Java 7/8. And obviously, I am aware of

- [SO: Icon with different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247653/which-icon-sizes-to-use-with-a-jframes-seticonimages-method)
- [SO: Loading icon via ClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657569/how-to-set-icon-to-jframe)

Does Java change the icon when I re-execute the `setIconImage` or `setIconImages` during the runtime?

Comment: The better solution is to find a library which does this nativly, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167037/windows-7-taskbar-progress-bar-in-java) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165484/task-bar-progress)

Comment: As to your actual question - have you tried?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Not yet - but I will let you know