# How can I get the window handle (hWnd) for a Stage in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-2, jna, javafx-8, hwnd

We're building a JavaFX application in Windows, and we want to be able to do some things to manipulate how our application appears in the Windows 7/8 taskbar.  This requires modifying a Windows variable called the "[Application User Model ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)".

We've already managed to do exactly what we want in Swing by using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna#readme), and we'd like to repeat our solution in JavaFX.  Unfortunately, to do this, we need to be able to retrieve the `hWnd` (window handle) for each window in our application.    This can be done in Swing/AWT via the JNA [Native.getWindowPointer()](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#getWindowPointer%28java.awt.Window%29) method, which works with `java.awt.Window`, but I can't figure out a good way to do this with a `javafx.stage.Window`.

Does anyone know of any way to do get `hWnd` for a `Stage`?

Comment: Could you look at this feature request, and say, does it contain things, which are interesting for you? http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24249

Comment: @Alexander: this does seem to have the right idea, though I doubt they will implement anything that lets us do what we need to with the taskbar (we have a single application that needs to show up with several different icons in the taskbar.)  We really do need hWnd, I think.   Thanks for the link though, I've added a comment to that RFE.

Comment: You can vote up that feature, if you want to rise its possibility to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a JavaFX2 version (uses Stage rather than Window):

```
private static Pointer getWindowPointer(Stage stage) {
    try {
        TKStage tkStage = stage.impl_getPeer();
        Method getPlatformWindow = tkStage.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getPlatformWindow" );
        getPlatformWindow.setAccessible(true);
        Object platformWindow = getPlatformWindow.invoke(tkStage);
        Method getNativeHandle = platformWindow.getClass().getMethod( "getNativeHandle" );
        getNativeHandle.setAccessible(true);
        Object nativeHandle = getNativeHandle.invoke(platformWindow);
        return new Pointer((Long) nativeHandle);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println("Error getting Window Pointer");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works anymore as of at least 1.8_66.  "getPlatformWindow" no longer seems to exist in TKStage.

Comment: Looks like it has been moved to the WindowStage class.  Anyone know how to get there?

Comment: Duh, WindowStage is a subclass of TKStage.  The method is found via reflection, but I'm getting an InvocationException when invoking the method.

Answer (score 5):

Add a dependency on JNA:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
  <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then give your `Stage` a distinct title ("MyStage" in this example), and then get the Window ID like this:

```
WinDef.HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, "MyStage");

long wid = Pointer.nativeValue(hwnd.getPointer());
```

This will work on Windows regardless of JavaFX version.

Answer (score 4):

The following code works for me in JavaFX 11 on Windows (I only need it there). I haven't tested it in any other version.

It's quite brittle, but manageable in my case, as I bundle the Java Runtime with the application so I always know what's underneath.

If you use Java 9 modules, you also need to open up the packages to your calling module:

`--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.stage=com.example` and `--add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=com.example`

```
package com.example;

import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class FXWinUtil {

    public static WinDef.HWND getNativeHandleForStage(Stage stage) {
        try {
            final Method getPeer = Window.class.getDeclaredMethod("getPeer", null);
            getPeer.setAccessible(true);
            final Object tkStage = getPeer.invoke(stage);
            final Method getRawHandle = tkStage.getClass().getMethod("getRawHandle");
            getRawHandle.setAccessible(true);
            final Pointer pointer = new Pointer((Long) getRawHandle.invoke(tkStage));
            return new WinDef.HWND(pointer);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Unable to determine native handle for window");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using JNA (which is likely if you're doing hackish stuff like this), you can also profit from `WinDef.HWND`.

Answer (score 2):

The following method shows how you can get a native window handle (hWnd) for a JavaFX Stage (or [Window](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/stage/Window.html)) and then store it in a JNA [Pointer](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html) object:

```
private static Pointer getWindowPointer(javafx.stage.Window window) {
    Pointer retval = null;
    try {
        Method getPeer = window.getClass().getMethod("impl_getPeer");
        final Object tkStage = getPeer.invoke(window);
        Method getPlatformWindow = tkStage.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getPlatformWindow");
        getPlatformWindow.setAccessible(true);
        final Object platformWindow = getPlatformWindow.invoke(tkStage);
        Method getNativeHandle = platformWindow.getClass().getMethod("getNativeHandle");
        retval = new Pointer((Long) getNativeHandle.invoke(platformWindow));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.err.println("Error getting Window Pointer");
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retval;
}
```

This solution is fragile and generally undesirable, since it uses reflection to access a bunch of private methods.  But it gets the job done.  Hopefully Oracle will eventually give us direct access to native window handles so we don't have to do this.

Of course, this code only works when you're running on MS Windows.  Also, I've only tried it out with early release builds of JavaFX 8 (but I suspect it will work fine on JavaFX 2 as well. EDIT: looks like it doesn't work in JavaFX 2.)

Comment: JavaFX 2 user here. Windows 7, jdk1.7.0_21. `m.invoke( window )` returns `null`. Solution not working.

Comment: Added a JavaFX2 version as a separate answer. FWIW.

Comment: Actually, this is already a JavaFX2 version.  Window is a superclass of Stage.

Answer (score 1):

```
com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows.get(0).getNativeWindow
```

//

```
com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getFocusedWindow.getNativeWindow
```

Comment: This has worked for me. No reflection, no extra dependencies, just a simple method to call.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for JavaFX 16, written on Kotlin (only Reflection)

```kotlin
fun getPointer(scene: Scene): Long {
    val tkStage = SceneHelper.getPeer(scene)

    val windowStage = tkStage.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("getWindowStage")
        .apply { isAccessible = true }
        .invoke(tkStage)

    val platformWindow = windowStage.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("getPlatformWindow")
        .apply { isAccessible = true }
        .invoke(windowStage)
    
    // Use fields 'ptr' and 'delegatePtr' instead of getNativeHandle() to avoid Platform.runLater
    val ptr = Window::class.java.getDeclaredField("ptr")
        .apply { isAccessible = true }[platformWindow] as Long

    val delegatePtr = Window::class.java.getDeclaredField("delegatePtr")
        .apply { isAccessible = true }[platformWindow] as Long

    return if (delegatePtr != 0L) delegatePtr else ptr
}
```