# How to make MouseTransparent Stage in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, transparent, stage

I've wanted to make JavaFX app that would display a crosshair in a middle of screen, but whenever I hover on the ImageView I can't do background tasks, like it blocks my mouse events.

I've tried using `Node#setMouseTransparent` but it didn't really work, same for `Scene.setFill(null)`

This is the code I have now:

```
    private void setStageProperties() {
        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getBounds();

        stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());

        Scene scene = new Scene(this);
        scene.setFill(null);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        this.primary = new Stage();
        primary.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        primary.setOpacity(0);
        primary.setHeight(0);
        primary.setWidth(0);
        primary.show();

        stage.initOwner(primary);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);


        double centerX = bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2;
        double centerY = bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2;

        stage.setX(centerX - stage.getWidth() / 2);
        stage.setY(centerY - stage.getHeight() / 2);

    }
```

```
    public CrosshairScene() {
        this.stage = new Stage();
        this.crosshairImage = new ImageView("crosshair.png");
        this.crosshairImage.setPickOnBounds(false);
        this.setMouseTransparent(true);
        this.setCenter(crosshairImage);
        this.setStageProperties();
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: null;");
    }
```

Run configuration:

[image: run config]

```
--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.stage=com.example.demo --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=com.example.demo
```

Comment: can't I use somehow JNA to make it transparent, just like some java swing app has

Comment: https://github.com/aeris170/Crosshair-Overlay/blob/master/src/xhair/Overlay.java#L157

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a proper [mre]? Because I swear making the stage transparent/undecorated, making the scene transparent, and having all nodes under the mouse either mouse-transparent or having no background/fill (even partially, e.g., an image with transparent pixels) allowed you to interact with whatever was behind the stage in the past. At least, I believe it worked with Windows 10 (though not on other platforms, such as macOS).

Comment: I've tried copying the code from java swing JNA and changed with javafx but it didn't really work :/ nothing changed at all. Also combining Java Swing and JavaFX is very uncomfortable because of import differences

Comment: Your run configuration is wrong.  You have supplied virtual machine (VM) arguments as program arguments instead of supplying them as VM arguments.  VM arguments need to be provided *before* the class to run.  Study [How to set JVM arguments in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-intellij-idea). Remove the VM arguments from the program arguments.  Choose `Modify options | Add VM options`, then add the VM arguments in the box that says "VM options".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [node `mouseTransparent` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#mouseTransparentProperty) just makes the node mouse transparent in the context of the JavaFX application, not concerning the JavaFX application and the rest of the windowing system.  To be able to do that, you need to change the window style in the native window system.

#### Solution for Windows 11

Here is a Windows only solution, based on the ideas from:

- [How can I get the window handle (hWnd) for a Stage in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034407/how-can-i-get-the-window-handle-hwnd-for-a-stage-in-javafx)
- https://github.com/aeris170/Crosshair-Overlay/blob/master/src/xhair/Overlay.java#L157

Run with VM args:

```
--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.stage=com.example.demo --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=com.example.demo
```

*src/main/java/module-info.java*

```
module com.example.demo {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires com.sun.jna;
    requires com.sun.jna.platform;

    exports com.example.demo;
}
```

*src/main/java/com/example/demo/TransparentApplication.java*

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;
import javafx.stage.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TransparentApplication extends Application {
    private static final String CROSSHAIR_SVG_PATH =
            """
            M 14,8 A 6,6 0 0 1 8,14 6,6 0 0 1 2,8 6,6 0 0 1 8,2 6,6 0 0 1 14,8 Z M 8 0 L 8 6.5 M 0 8 L 6.5 8 M 8 9.5 L 8 16 M 9.5 8 L 16 8
            """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane layout = new StackPane(
                new Group(
                        createCrosshair()
                )
        );
        layout.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        layout.setMouseTransparent(true);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, Color.TRANSPARENT);

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        makeMouseTransparent(stage);
    }

    private static Node createCrosshair() {
        SVGPath path = new SVGPath();
        path.setContent(CROSSHAIR_SVG_PATH);
        path.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        path.setStroke(
                Color.BLUEVIOLET.deriveColor(
                        0, 1, 1, .6
                )
        );
        path.setScaleX(10);
        path.setScaleY(10);

        return path;
    }

    private static void makeMouseTransparent(Stage stage) {
        WinDef.HWND hwnd = getNativeHandleForStage(stage);
        int wl = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowLong(hwnd, WinUser.GWL_EXSTYLE);
        wl = wl | WinUser.WS_EX_LAYERED | WinUser.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
        User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(hwnd, WinUser.GWL_EXSTYLE, wl);
    }

    private static WinDef.HWND getNativeHandleForStage(Stage stage) {
        try {
            final Method getPeer = Window.class.getDeclaredMethod("getPeer", (Class<?>[]) null);
            getPeer.setAccessible(true);
            final Object tkStage = getPeer.invoke(stage);
            final Method getRawHandle = tkStage.getClass().getMethod("getRawHandle");
            getRawHandle.setAccessible(true);
            final Pointer pointer = new Pointer((Long) getRawHandle.invoke(tkStage));
            return new WinDef.HWND(pointer);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Unable to determine native handle for window");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>TransparentApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TransparentApp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

#### Execution commands

Example commands to run from the command line from the project root directory.  Provided for Windows 11 with JDK 21, and assuming you have already run `mvn clean install` to build the application.

```
set JAVA_HOME=%userprofile%\.jdks\openjdk-21.0.1
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
set M2=%userprofile%\.m2\repository

java --add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.stage=com.example.demo --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=com.example.demo -p %M2%\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.14.0\jna-5.14.0.jar;%M2%\org\openjfx\javafx-base\21.0.1\javafx-base-21.0.1-win.jar;%M2%\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\5.14.0\jna-platform-5.14.0.jar;%M2%\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\21.0.1\javafx-graphics-21.0.1-win.jar;%M2%\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\21.0.1\javafx-controls-21.0.1-win.jar;target\classes -m com.example.demo/com.example.demo.TransparentApplication
```

These commands are just provided for testing purposes.  Usually you can configure VM arguments in your IDE run configuration.  Or, the application would be linked and packaged using `jlink` or `jpackage` (probably via a build tool plugin for Maven or Gradle), with VM arguments specified in the startup script included in the application packaging, then the installed application could be run by double click.

#### Running from IntelliJ Idea

Supply virtual machine (VM) arguments *not program arguments*. VM arguments need to be provided *before* the class to run. Choose `Modify options | Add VM options`, then add the VM arguments in the box that says "VM options", as shown in this answer:

- [How to set JVM arguments in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-intellij-idea)

#### Alternate solution

This proposal does not break modularity and rely on JNA access from your application code (I did not try it though).

Unless you change the window settings, similar to as defined above for Windows, the window displaying the JavaFX content will intercept the mouse actions. Maybe you could do something tricky like capture the mouse input, then hide the stage momentarily, and trigger a mouse action using the [Robot](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html), perhaps in conjunction with some `Platform.runLater` calls, but that is a bit of a hack.

#### Additional info

As noted in comments by Slaw:

> Because I swear making the stage transparent/undecorated, making the scene transparent, and having all nodes under the mouse either mouse-transparent or having no background/fill (even partially, e.g., an image with transparent pixels) allowed you to interact with whatever was behind the stage in the past. At least, I believe it worked with Windows 10 (though not on other platforms, such as macOS).

I checked with Windows 11 Pro and JavaFX 21.0.1.  It worked mostly as Slaw remembered.  If you clicked on the transparent area of the stage, the mouse interacted with the window under the stage.

However, if you clicked on non-transparent areas of the stage, then the mouse actions did not register in the window under the stage, unless the JNA code provided in this answer was used.

#### FAQ

The error:

```
module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.stage" to module com.example.demo
```

means that your VM arguments are wrong.

This VM argument was not picked up when you ran your application:

```
--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.stage=com.example.demo
```

`com.example.demo` is the module name in this case, not the package name. Unless your module is also named `com.example.demo`, it will not work. See the [java man page for the `--add-opens` switch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html#extra-options-for-java) for more information.

#### Linking via jlink

The jna team currently provide two versions of the jna artifacts.  One is designed to the work with the Java Platform Module System (JPMS).  If you wish to jlink your application, you need to use the JPMS version, which has a `-jpms` extension.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna-platform-jpms</artifactId>
    <version>5.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :/ It creates transparent Stage with the SVG Image, but I can't click and do actions through it.

Comment: well I made everything 1:1 so idk, no errors at all. It did work on java swing app though

Comment: could you please tell me your discord if possible?

Comment: I've changed JVM arguments for my package `com.example.demo` instead of `com.example`

Comment: I have `module com.example.demo {` so I it shouild be correct :/ well idk what could be wrong.

Unable to make com.sun.javafx.tk.TKStage javafx.stage.Window.getPeer() accessible: module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.stage" to module com.example.demo

thtis is the error I get. I've also tried getting HWND by Stage.getName() (window name)

Comment: I have `--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.stage=com.example.demo --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=com.example.demo`

my `module-info.java`:
```java
module com.example.demo {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires com.sun.jna;
    requires com.sun.jna.platform;

    exports com.example.demo;
}
```

Comment: I am using com.example.demo already and I set it in Run Configuration in Intellij IDEA

Comment: Updated answer to address comments in the answer.